# create ad hoc, over the air, iOS 5.1 ipad app on xcode 4.5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I want to know how I can build an ad hoc, over the air, app that runs on an iPad 1 (running iOS 5.1.1) from xcode 4.5.1.  I have installed the iPad 5.1 simulator and it works OK on that, it also works fine on an iPad 1 when installed over the wire.  However it will not install (on iPad 1 only, iPad 2+ is fine) when I create an ad hoc, over the air distribution.  In `project->build settings` I have `Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)` and `iOS Deployment Target: iOS 5.1`.
Any ideas anyone?

Please note, I already know how to create an "over the air" distribution.  This question is about a particular problem with installing on an iPad 1.

Comment: Have you checked that the iPad 1's UDID is selected in the Ad Hoc distribution profile at the [developer site](http://developer.apple.com)?

Comment: Yes @jjv360, I have.  All the company's iPad's (we have 1s, 2s, and 3s) have their UDIDs in the profile.  It just doesn't work for the iPad 1s.  It used to be fine, but stopped working at some point.  I think perhaps there was an xcode upgrade involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to this was to set the build settings to 5.1 in both the project and the target.  I did this recently in xcode 4.6 and that seemed to solve the problem (of not being able to deploy to the iPad 1).  I note that the base SDK is still showing 6.1.